# can't access to the POST variable that sent from register form in django

Tags: django, forms, jquery

I have a register form in html that has a button that type of `submit` and the name of `registerSubmit` like this:

```
<input class="RegisterButton right green" name="registerSubmit" type="submit" value="Continue">
```

I want to check the form with Ajax and then if every thing is valid then redirect the user to her/his profile.But when I want to redirect the user to his/her profile I can't send the submit input that its name is `registerSubmit`. here is a section of JQuery code that related to this event:

```
$("#mainRegisterForm").submit(function(event){
    var thisRegisterForm = $(this);
    $(".ajaxLogoRegister").show();
    event.preventDefault();
    var firstName = $("input[name='firstname']").val();
    var lastName = $("input[name='lastname']").val();
    var emailAddress = $("input[name='email']").val();
    var password = $("input[name='password']").val();
    var rePass = $("input[name='rePass']").val();
    var sex = "NULL";
    if ($("input[name='gender']").is(":checked")){
        sex = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
    }
    var data ={
        firstname:firstName,
        lastname:lastName,
        emailaddress:emailAddress,
        password:password,
        repass:rePass,
        sex:sex
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/registercheck',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(result){
            if(result.fn==0){
                //do some stuff
            }
            //another if conditions that checks the validity of every field of refister form
            ...
            ...
            $(".ajaxLogoRegister").hide();
            if(result.isOK=='1'){ //isOK = 1 when every filed is valid and user must redirect to his/her profile
                thisRegisterForm.unbind('submit').submit();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My main problem is that when I click the registerSubmit button in `views.py` the `request.POST.get('registerSubmit')` returns `None` object instead of `Continue` value.
when I don't use Ajax and send the form normally `registerSubmit` value is Continue and every thing is OK.where I am wrong?

Comment: Are you actually submitting a POST with that ajax request? If you watch network in chrome dev tools or firebug what do you see? you might need to set ```type: "POST"``` on the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

[By default, `$.ajax();` will issue a GET request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), not a POST. You need to specify that in your ajax options. Second, I don't see where you're accessing the value of the element named "registerSubmit". I see an "rePass", but you're not including the value you're expecting to find in the request.

You need to either specifically set the "type" ajax option `type` to "POST" or retrieve the `method` property from the form element:

```
$ajax({
    url: 'ajax/registercheck',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    ....
});
```

Comment: I access the `registerSubmit` in the `views.py`.I check the validity of the form with ajax and then in server(because javascript can change by client and may be dangerous)when I want to check in server I don't access to the variable `registerSubmit` that sent from template. also I add type:'POST' but ajax request sent but not response(I found it from ajax loading icon that I use in my form)

Comment: If you're doing a POST via Ajax, only the data you serialize in JavaScript will be sent to the server. In order to access `registerSubmit`, you have to serialize the field and send it to the server.